# Renormalization of linear sigma model fixing the Vacuum Expectation Value (VEV)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, symmetry-breaking, sigma-models

In the linear sigma model
$$ \mathcal L = (\partial_{\mu} \phi^i)^2 + \frac 12 \mu_0 (\phi^i)^2 + \frac{\lambda_0}{4} ((\phi^i)^2)^2 ,$$
the symmetry is broken around the vacuum expectation value (VEV)
$$ \phi = (0, \ldots, 0, v) \quad v = \frac{\mu_0}{\sqrt{\lambda_0}}.$$
We gain $N-1$ massless $\pi^i$ and one $2\mu_0^2$-massive $\sigma$ fields.

---

Take for semplicity $N=2$. The lagrangian of the linear sigma model around the VEV is 
$$ \mathcal L = (\partial_{\mu} \sigma)^2 + (\partial_{\mu} \pi)^2 - \frac 12 (2\mu^2_0) \sigma^2 + \mathcal L_I,$$
where
$$ \mathcal L_I = - \frac{\lambda_0}{4}\sigma^4 - \frac{\lambda_0}{4}\pi^4 - \frac{\lambda_0}{2}\sigma^2\pi^2 - \sqrt{\lambda_0}\mu_0\sigma^3 - \sqrt{\lambda_0}\mu_0 \sigma \pi^2 .$$

Following Peskin & Schroeder, I want to renormalize the theory with fixed $v$ so that the VEV won't gain contributions from the renormalization process.

**Question**: To fix $v$ reduce the parameters of the lagrangian to two: the field strength $Z$ and the coupling constant $\lambda_0$, while $\mu_0 = \sqrt{\lambda_0} v$ is no more an independent parameter. Why Peskin & Schroeder use the $\delta \mu$ counterterm? In other words, why they regularize the theory using three renormalization conditions if one parameter is fixed? Aren't two conditions sufficient?

Probably I misunderstood the meaning of (eq 11.16):

> The realtion $\langle \phi^N \rangle = \mu / \sqrt{\lambda}$ is
>   satisfied to all orders in perturbation theory.